# MySql Add onto an exisiting entry in the database

Tags: mysql

Just wondering is it possible to add onto an exisiting entry in the database without having to do a query to look whats in there?

Ive done it with numbers before like

```
UPDATE table SET views = views +1
```

But is there a way to do it with a string?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `concat`?

Comment: You may also want to look into [`CONCAT_WS()` Concatenate With Separator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) – Otherwise, your added string(s) may be all bunched up into `OneBigClump` that could also end up looking like `veryhardtoreadthisaddedtextIaddedthisafterthenIaddedthistoo`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is CONCAT() function:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

```
UPDATE table SET field = CONCAT(field, "some str" ) WHERE id = 123;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE table SET views = CONCAT(views,'some text to add on to it')
```